# Needing Some Help With this Recurrence Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Ishaan only cooks 1 of 4 meals: pesto chicken, eggplant parmesan, peanut noodles, or
cauliflower wings. His only rule is that he never makes peanut noodles two or more days in
a row.

Let $a_n$ represent the number of ways Ishaan can choose meals across $n$ days (where $n\ge 0$).

**My Thinking:**

From the past day we can say there is three ways to choose what Ishaan ate, so $3a_{n-1}$. Then the day before that there is three ways to choose what Ishaan ate, so $3a_{n-2}$.

Then all together I have: $a_n = 3a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$, but I don't think this is right.

I was wondering if someone could help me with getting the correct recurrence formula and inital conditions. I am lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recurrence is correct, but your explanation for it doesn’t make much sense.

On day $n$ Ishaan can cook pesto chicken, eggplant parmesan, or cauliflower wings no matter what he made on day $n-1$; that accounts for $3a_{n-1}$ possible sequences of $n$ meals. He can also cook peanut noodles **if** he did not cook them on day $n-1$. No matter what he cooked on day $n-2$, he could have cooked any one of the other three dishes on day $n-1$, so there are $3a_{n-2}$ sequences of $n-1$ meals that do **not** end with peanut noodles on day $n-1$. Each of these sequences allows him to cook peanut noodles on day $n$, so each of them contributes one more possible sequence of $n$ meals, for a total of $a_n=3a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$ possible sequences of $n$ meals.

The initial conditions are $a_0=1$ and $a_1=4$: there is only one empty sequence of meals, and on day $1$ he can cook any one of the $4$ meals.